# Free JSON formatted stock quote API (live or historical)

Tags: api, live, stock

I have an project where i implement live stock updates of various companies of all countries.

Can any one tell me where  we can find "Free API" to fetch these details. I  already search a lot on Google only found "Pro API". Need help :)

Comment: You can download from google easily enough still using an undocumented API. http://www.jarloo.com/real-time-google-stock-api/

Comment: As a software developer, I would recommend [Alpha Vantage](http://www.alphavantage.co/). They offer free JSON APIs for realtime and historical stock quotes. [Here](http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo) is their realtime intraday data for MSFT. [Here](http://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) is their full API documentation. You do need an API key, which can be obtained for free on their website.

Comment: While Alpha Vantage looks promising from a data point of view, it's pretty sketchy that they don't describe their business model or have an "About Us" page detailing company contact info, address, and information about the human beings who work there. I'd love to use their API, but they don't look too trustworthy to me.

Comment: @SteveCarino is it realtime data or delayed data by 15mins?

Answer (score 50):

Check the following they are free, they generate Json, though for different exchanges you need to ensure that correct syntax is used. even Yahoo finance works well, but it has some issues regarding NSE and BSE data, which is always generated Null

`DEPRECATED`Google Finance - NSE

```
URL - http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AIAENG,ATULAUTO,<Add more NSE codes>
```

`DEPRECATED` Google Finance - BSE

```
URL -http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=BOM:524091,532683,<Add more BSE codes>
```

`DEPRECATED` Other Data Feeds (Json)

```
URL - http://live-nse.herokuapp.com/?symbol=AIAENG,ATULAUTO,<Add more NSE codes>
```

Python Utility (NSE)

```
URL - http://nsetools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need stock rates of all companies without mention any company name. Thanks is advance.

Comment: You can use this as mentioned above http://nsetools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html. If you want to have quotes of all companies, then you can use *get_stock_codes* API and then iterate over that. Implement threading to get you job done faster.

Comment: Wasn't Google Finance API [deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html)?

Comment: I use it in my application, works fine, and results are also up to date

Comment: As a software developer, I would recommend [Alpha Vantage](http://www.alphavantage.co/). They offer free JSON APIs for realtime and historical stock quotes. [Here](http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo) is their realtime intraday data for MSFT. [Here](http://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) is their full API documentation. You do need an API key, which can be obtained for free on their website.

Comment: this api is depreciated and its not working from Sep 2017.
It is always return 404 error.

Comment: Yahoo is no longer working for me. Google Finance was deprecated. But, I found a great replacement. They use standard REST APIs, return JSON, and their "sandbox" membership is free: https://developer.tradier.com/documentation