# How to retrieve live price from yahoo_finance stock?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am building an application and i want to retrieve the latest quoted price from yahoo-finance. I am trying to scrape the path using BeautifulSoup, however all I get when I print is an empty list. Any suggestions?

Example HTML:

```html
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35"><!-- react-text: 36 -->169.37<!-- /react-text --></span>
```

My code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 a = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'lxml')
 search = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) 
 D(ib)'})
 print(search)
```

Comment: The content of the page is probably brought in by ajax - you wont be able to scape it. If you are lucky they provide an APOI so you need not to scrape anything - simply use the API.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Do you know if there is a way that I can scrap live stock prices? Perhaps from another source? thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794418/free-json-formatted-stock-quote-api-live-or-historical

Comment: You should use [this library](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance)

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium in combination with BeautifulSoup to get the content you are after. Something like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
item = soup.find(id="quote-market-notice").find_parent().find("span").text
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
169.37
```

Comment: I am currently using visual studio and i get  an error with bs4 although i have got it installed. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: When it comes to give any suggestion about installing stuff, my head spins. You can google to find any solution as to how you can get `bs4` working. Btw, the above piece of code is worth trying for. Thanks.

Comment: It is working almost perfectly. I just have a question. When i run the code a Chrome webpage pops up with the url i provided in the code above. How can i stop this?? I just want to get the number. Thank you

Comment: in that case you need to choose `headless chrome driver`, `phantomjs` or drivers like that. However, there are some issues in those headless drivers when it comes to deal with click event or infinite scrolling webpages.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.set_headless()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts); you can use this method to scrape data without pops up

Answer (score 1):

found a python api:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

```
>>> from yahoo_finance import Share   
>>> yahoo = Share('YHOO')  
>>> print yahoo.get_open()  
'36.60'  
>>> print yahoo.get_price()  
'36.84'  
>>> print yahoo.get_trade_datetime()  
'2014-02-05 20:50:00 UTC+0000'
```

at a guess, this will be easier to use and break less

Comment: Well, it is not working. I get a YQLquerryError! Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the yahoo_fin package (see http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/).   Here's a couple examples:

```
# load the stock_info module from yahoo_fin
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

# get Apple's live quote price
si.get_live_price("AAPL")

# or Amazon's
si.get_live_price("AMZN")
```

Just replace "AAPL" or "AMZN" with whatever ticker you need.